How to get class name from PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Property
I am creating a Rector (rector/rector) rule that should alter properties based on some of their attributes.
PhpParser is from nikic/php-parser.
I have no problem fetching the Properties, I simply check if current \PhpParser\Node is an instance of \PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Property (and I do get matches).
However, for my use case to match some change source data, I also need the class name of the class the property belongs to - I tried following naive implementation:
    private function getClassNameFromPropertyNode(Property $propertyNode): ?string {
        $currentNode = $propertyNode;
        while ($currentNode !== null) {
            if ($currentNode instanceof \PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_) {
                $name = $currentNode->name;
                return $name instanceof \PhpParser\Node\Identifier ? $name->toString() : null;
            }
            $currentNode =  $currentNode->getAttribute('parent');
        }
        return null;
    }

But it always gets me null ... it seems that $currentNode->getAttribute('parent') this always return null.
How do I get the parent node of current node and/or the class name of the current property? Thank you.

I think I solved it. I got back to https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/issues/238 and it got me an idea - the parent attribute is probably not being set by rector and I was right.
There were actually 2 issues:

parent node not being set as parent attribute
getNodeTypes() of the rector rules did not even go through the classes

So first, I needed to also go through the Class_ nodes:
use PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Property;
use PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_;
    ...
    public function getNodeTypes(): array
    {
        return [
            Property::class,
            Class_::class,
        ];
    }

And then in each refactor() call set the parent attribute to the current class FQN (fully qualified name = name with the namespace) - to do that I first simplified the method to get the class name:
    private function getPropertyClassFqn(Property $propertyNode): ?string {
        $class = $propertyNode->getAttribute('parent');
        return ($class instanceof Class_) ? $class->namespacedName->toString() : null;
    }

And then at the start of each refactor() I set the parent.
This is based on the assumption that the Rector will always go from top to bottom in the tree.
use PhpParser\Node;
...
    public function refactor(Node $node): ?Node
    {
        if ($node instanceof Class_)
        {
            foreach ($node->stmts ?? [] as $childNode)
            {
                if ($childNode instanceof Property)
                {
                    $childNode->setAttribute('parent', $node);
                }
            }
            return $node;
        }

